# Change position of <div> in <div class>

Tags: css

I am looking to change the position of a div that is inside a div class. My only option is to add CSS, I cannot edit the HTML. The current code looks like this:

```
<div class="additional-information">
 <div>
 <strong> Name </strong>
 <strong> Address </strong>
</div>
```

What I managed to do is to change the position of the entire 'additional-information' class with the following code:

```
    .additional-information {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  bottom: -230px;
  }
```

Would it be possible to move individual divs inside this class that have no tag?

Comment: *Would it be possible to move individual divs inside this class that have no tag* No, because without a tag they cannot be `<div>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with CSS Child Selector.

Something like this:

```css
.additional-information > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  bottom: -230px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="additional-information">
  I am a parent
    <div>
      <strong>name</strong>
      <strong>address</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more info look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) article.